# HTTP code 0 returned by cloudfront

Tags: http, amazon-cloudfront

Setup:

I have an API hosted on AWS and using cloudfront for the same.

Problem:

Analyzing cloudfront logs we came across requests which were returned csstatus(HTTP) 0.

What does it mean??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a `csstatus`, so I assume you are referring to `sc-status`.

> `000`, which indicates that the viewer closed the connection (for example, closed the browser tab) before CloudFront could respond to a request
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#LogFileFormat